# developer name is invalid in salesforce1

Tags: developername

I am getting this error in salesforce1 when opening a report.This report is running well in salesforce classic but not in salesforce1.

Thanks
Tarachand

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that your report was created on the Desktop version. Now on Salesforce1, reports are available but not all types. All reports on Salesforce1 will be shown as Tabular reports. On top of that, if you have Grouping added, then your grouping fields will be put as the last columns on the report when viewing in Salesforce1.

Comment: Hi ron , actually I am getting this error 'This developer name is invalid. Provide the developer name for the report that contain the chart' and report not opening in salesforce1

Comment: and what will i have to do to show these reports in salesfoce1 as well as salesforce classic